# Pair bluetooth just inside Application

Tags: android, ios, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm working on university project that consists in audio speaker with bluetooth connected to mobile application (iOS and Android), but the audio just works in Application, but not with mobile music for example.

It's possible to pair module bluetooth just inside mobile Application ?

If someone know some projects doing something similar, or information/example code that pairing an Application, or useful information for me I would appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: I will go watch it now, thanks.